# Inserting data and point into a table PostGIS / Error: parse

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

I'm trying to import in a table with columns (name, x, y, geom) like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO public.table (name, x, y, geom)
VALUES ('name', X, Y, ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POINT(X,Y)', SRC))
```

But I'm obtaining this error:

> ERROR:  parse error - invalid geometry
> SQL state: XX000

X, Y and SRC are integers. I've wrote X and Y as generic.

What's going on?

Comment: WKT only uses commas *between* vertices, not *within* them. You've presented a single part point with two vertices, but only one dimension each.

Answer (score 1):

In PostGIS, to insert a geometry/point into a table ('table' in your case), by converting its WKT value, you rather use this :

```
INSERT INTO public.table (name, x, y, geom)
VALUES ('name', X, Y, ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POINT(X Y)', SRC))
```

The X and Y values should not be separated by a comma. Take a look at the official documentation : [ST_GeomFromText](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ST_GeomFromText.html)